# Exposing DataGridView's columns property in UserControl doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I put a `DataGridView` in a `UserControl` and create a public property in my usercontrol that exposes datagridview's columns property.
Here is the sample code:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataGridViewColumnCollection MyDataGridColumns
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView1.Columns;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I add `UserControl1` in my form and I click on `MyDataGridColumns` property in property window and add 1 or more columns. **The problem happens when I rebuild my solution; All of the columns that I have just added disappear after rebuilding.**

Can anyone explain to me why this happens? and how to solve it?

Comment: How are you adding the columns? In design mode or programmatically?

Comment: Try to add a setter to your property `MyDataGridColumns`.

Comment: @Bioukh, Already tried it, Adding setter doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @AfshinAghazadeh...Do you feel the answers below solved your problem finally?

Comment: @S.Akbari That was the best answer yet because now I know the problem at least that's why i voted it, but I need a way to expose the inner DataGrid.Columns properly so I can change it's columns in design time to make a good UserControl.

Comment: @AfshinAghazadeh I shared an answer to a similar question here: [Expose Columns property of a DataGridView in UserControl and make it editable via Designer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36794920/3110834) Hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me : I created a specific columns editor as it seems it is impossible to use the default columns editor for any control that does not extend `DataGridView`.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, IDataGridView
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public DataGridView DataGridView
    {
        get { return dataGridView1; }
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor(typeof(ExtendedDataGridViewColumnCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [MergableProperty(false)]
    public DataGridViewColumnCollection MyDataGridColumns
    {
        get { return dataGridView1.Columns; }
    }

}

public interface IDataGridView
{
    DataGridView DataGridView { get; }
}

class ExtendedDataGridViewColumnCollectionEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    private Form dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog;

    private ExtendedDataGridViewColumnCollectionEditor() { }

    private static Form CreateColumnCollectionDialog(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.Load(typeof(ControlDesigner).Assembly.ToString());
        var type = assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog");

        var ctr = type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)[0];
        return (Form)ctr.Invoke(new object[] { provider });
    }

    public static void SetLiveDataGridView(Form form, DataGridView grid)
    {
        var mi = form.GetType().GetMethod("SetLiveDataGridView", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        mi.Invoke(form, new object[] { grid });
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        if (provider != null && context != null)
        {
            var service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
            if (service == null || context.Instance == null)
                return value;

            var host = (IDesignerHost)provider.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
            if (host == null)
                return value;

            if (dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog == null)
                dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog = CreateColumnCollectionDialog(provider);

            //Unfortunately we had to make property which returns inner datagridview  
            //to access it here because we need to pass DataGridView into SetLiveDataGridView () method 
            var grid = ((IDataGridView)context.Instance).DataGridView;
            //we have to set Site property because it will be accessed inside SetLiveDataGridView () method 
            //and by default it's usually null, so if we do not set it here, we will get exception inside SetLiveDataGridView () 
            var oldSite = grid.Site;
            grid.Site = ((UserControl)context.Instance).Site;
            //execute SetLiveDataGridView () via reflection 
            SetLiveDataGridView(dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog, grid);

            using (var transaction = host.CreateTransaction("DataGridViewColumnCollectionTransaction"))
            {
                if (service.ShowDialog(dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog) == DialogResult.OK)
                    transaction.Commit();
                else
                    transaction.Cancel();
            }
            //we need to set Site property back to the previous value to prevent problems with serializing our control 
            grid.Site = oldSite;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that works for me too for the DataGridView's Columns collection.  Now, how do we get all of the other Properties and Event Handlers in the Designer?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.0.3) using .NET 6 Windows Forms, the dialog's Add button does not raise the Add dialog. Add now only adds a new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, and there is no designer property for changing that column type.

Comment: @gridtrak You can modify the DataGridView column type directly in the Designer.cs file.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you didn't specify the type of the column. You should give the type of the column when adding a column (for example `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` or `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`). In your `Form1.cs` do the following:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataGridViewColumn dgViewColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();//Or DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    dgViewColumn.DataPropertyName = "dgViewColumn";
    dgViewColumn.HeaderText = @"dgViewColumn";
    dgViewColumn.Name = "dgViewColumn";
    userControl11.MyDataGridColumns.Add(dgViewColumn);
}
```

Comment: @Afshin Aghazadeh, Why do you insist on using the designer? Code offers way more control than the designer.

Answer (score 0):

[@Bioukh answer works in VS2019 and somewhat works in VS2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35287928/3519108). However, the results of embedding the DataGridView control in my UserControl then adding and editing the Columns using the *answer* does not enable those Columns to *migrate* to another instance of the UserControl.  For example: Copy/Paste the UserControl and all of the embedded DataGridView's columns disappear from the new copy.

To *Work Around* this issue I maintain my DataGridView instances as *native* and use a public DataGridView property in my UserControl with the binding and docking performed in the property setter.  I then drop my_UserControl on my form, drop my_DataGridView on my form, and then set my_UserControl.DataGridView = my_DataGridView. This work around preserves the *native properties and behaviors* associated with the DataGridView.

In my_UserControl, I have a *Panel* named "GridPanel" and a *VScrollBar*. I then added the following property:

```
///<summary>
/// Associates a native DataGridView with this UserControl
/// then sets the DataGridView.Parent to the Panel in this UserControl
/// and sets the DataGridView.Dock to Fill the Panel
///</summary>
public DataGridView? ContainedDataGridView
{
  get
  {
    try
    {
      // if we have a DataGridView in our Panel then return it
      if ((this.GridPanel.Controls.Count == 1)
          && (this.GridPanel.Controls[0] is DataGridView view))
      {
        return view;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      //// TODO Handle "ContainedDataGridView get error"
    }

    // Return null if there is no DataGridView or there was an error checking for it.
    return null;
  }
  set
  {
    try
    {
      // Clear the panel to prevent adding more than one DataGridView
      this.GridPanel.Controls.Clear();

      if (value is not null)              
      {
        this.GridPanel.Controls.Add(value);
        value.Parent = this.GridPanel;
        value.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      }
      // else the panel remains cleared
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      //// TODO Handle "ContainedDataGridView set error"
    }
  }
}
```

The above snippet is coded as C# 10, .NET 6, Windows Forms App, UserControl and tested in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.0.3