# Designer doesn't serialzie Columns of a DataGridView property of a UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, components, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to create a custom control that contains a label, a toolstrip and a Datagridview.

When the test form generates the Design code, it saves correctely the toolstrip items but it doesn't save the Datagridview columns.
**Code DGrid.cs**

```
...
    [DesignerAttribute(typeof(MultiDesigner))]
    public partial class FDGrid : Panel
    {
        ....
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        [Category("Bars"), Description("Barra dei comandi.")]
        public ToolStrip Barra
        {
            get { return _barra; }
            set { _barra = value; }
        }
        
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        [Category("Grid"), Description("Griglia dati.")]
        public DataGridView Griglia
        {
            get { return _griglia; }
            set { _griglia = value; }
        }
        ....
        
    }
    
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = 
        "FullTrust")]
    public class MultiDesigner : System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner
    {
        public override void Initialize(IComponent c)
        {
            base.Initialize(c);
            FDGrid ctl = (FDGrid)c;
            EnableDesignMode(ctl.Griglia, "Griglia");
            EnableDesignMode(ctl.Barra, "Barra");
        }
    }
...
```

**Code FDGrid.Designer.cs**

FDGrid.Designer.cs
....

```
private FDLabeledImage _titolo;
private ToolStrip _barra;
private DataGridView _griglia;
    

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this._barra = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
    this._griglia = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
    this._titolo = new FDControl.FDLabeledImage();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this._griglia)).BeginInit();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    ....
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this._griglia)).EndInit();
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

....

**Code Form1.Designer.cs**

```
....    
            
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.fdGrid1 = new FDControl.FDGrid();  // OK
                this.fdGrid1.Column1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(); **// Error** 
                this.toolStripLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel(); //OK
                
            }
            
            ...
            private FDControl.FDGrid fdGrid1; //OK
            private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel toolStripLabel1; //OK
            private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumnfdGrid1.Column1;//Error
...
```

help, I would like to understand where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant, but a working solution:

1. Create a custom `MyDataGridView` which derives from `DataGridView`:

   ```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.Design;
    using System.Drawing.Design;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
    public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
    {
        [Editor(typeof(ExtendedDataGridViewColumnCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        public new DataGridViewColumnCollection Columns { get => base.Columns; }

        private class ExtendedDataGridViewColumnCollectionEditor : UITypeEditor
        {
            private Form dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog;
            private ExtendedDataGridViewColumnCollectionEditor() { }
            private static Form CreateColumnCollectionDialog(IServiceProvider provider)
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.Load(typeof(ControlDesigner).Assembly.ToString());
                var type = assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog");
                var ctor = type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)[0];
                return (Form)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { provider });
            }
            public static void SetLiveDataGridView(Form form, DataGridView dgv)
            {
                var method = form.GetType().GetMethod("SetLiveDataGridView", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                method.Invoke(form, new object[] { dgv });
            }
            public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
            {
                if (provider != null && context != null)
                {
                    var service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
                    if (service == null || context.Instance == null)
                        return value;

                    var host = (IDesignerHost)provider.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
                    if (host == null)
                        return value;

                    if (dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog == null)
                        dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog = CreateColumnCollectionDialog(provider);

                    var dgv = ((MyDataGridView)context.Instance);
                    var oldSite = dgv.Site;
                    dgv.Site = ((MyDataGridView)context.Instance).Parent?.Site;
                    SetLiveDataGridView(dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog, dgv);

                    using (var transaction = host.CreateTransaction("DataGridViewColumnCollectionTransaction"))
                    {
                        if (service.ShowDialog(dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog) == DialogResult.OK)
                            transaction.Commit();
                        else
                            transaction.Cancel();
                    }
                    dgv.Site = oldSite;
                }
                return value;
            }
            public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            {
                return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. Build the solution.
3. Create your `UserControl` and drop an instance of `MyDataGridView` on it.
4. Expose the `DataGridView` property:

   ```
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public DataGridView DataGridView { get => dataGridView1; }
    }
   ```
5. Build the solution.
6. Drop an instance of `MyUserControl` on your form, then in property editor window, find the `DataGridView` property, expand it and edit `Columns` and Save the form.

The columns are serialized now. There you go.

**Note:** The custom `UITypeEditor` is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35287928/3110834) with some changes.

The result looks like:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ...
    ...

    this.Column1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    this.Column2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.myUserControl1.DataGridView)).BeginInit();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // myUserControl1
    // 
    // 
    // 
    // 
    this.myUserControl1.DataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
    this.myUserControl1.DataGridView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
    this.Column1,
    this.Column2});

    ...
    ...

    // 
    // Column1
    // 
    this.Column1.HeaderText = "Column1";
    this.Column1.MinimumWidth = 6;
    this.Column1.Name = "Column1";
    this.Column1.Width = 125;
    // 
    // Column2
    // 
    this.Column2.HeaderText = "Column2";
    this.Column2.MinimumWidth = 6;
    this.Column2.Name = "Column2";
    this.Column2.Width = 125;
    
    ...
    ...

    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.myUserControl1.DataGridView)).EndInit();
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}

...

private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column1;
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column2;

...
```

Comment: I removed unnecessary parts of the code which was remaining there based on my tests. (The custom ColumnCollection and override of CreateColumnCollectionDialog were unnecessary.)

Comment: Now it's probably the most elegant solution 

Comment: thanks for your reply and the time you have dedicated to me. 
In my case It doesn't work, when I add a column and save it app and visualstudio.

Comment: Well, the solution is tested in VS 2019 - .NET 4.8. I suggest you start with a clean project and exactly follow the steps. After you made it working, you can modify it to whatever you want to have in your control.

Comment: i confused component class and usercontrol in step 3. It works fine. Thanks

Comment: Last note: It works if I navigate in the DataGridView properties and change the columns (step 6) but it doesn't work if I change the columns with the datagridview menu editor (right click and edit column)

Comment: I'd create a custom designer as well or approach the problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54247547/3110834).

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022 .NET 6 Windows.Forms designer, I can the the DataGridViewColumnCollectionEditor dialog, but when I click "Add" I get an error "At least one of the DataGridView control's columns has no cell template."

Comment: @gridtrak I've tested it in .NET 4.X, but not with later versions, I'll try it and get back to you if I have something to share.