# Design-time properties of a DataGridView inside a user control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I have a user control which has, among other consituent controls, a DataGridView.
How can I expose the DataGridView's design-time properties, and in particular, the small arrow that lets the developer add or edit columns?

I found this:
[Designer doesn't serialzie Columns of a DataGridView property of a UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65441826/7444103)

I converted it to VB.net but I have compile issues... "InitalizeComponent", and "Return DGV" give "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

My user control is called "DataGridViewManager" and conains a DataGridView controls called "DGV" (and some others)

```
Public Class MyDataGridView
    Inherits DataGridView

    <Editor(GetType(ExtendedDataGridViewColumnCollectionEditor), GetType(UITypeEditor))>
    Public Overloads ReadOnly Property Columns As DataGridViewColumnCollection
        Get
            Return MyBase.Columns
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Class ExtendedDataGridViewColumnCollectionEditor
        Inherits UITypeEditor

        Private dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog As Form

        Private Sub New()
        End Sub

        Private Shared Function CreateColumnCollectionDialog(ByVal provider As IServiceProvider) As Form
            Dim myassembly = Assembly.Load(GetType(ControlDesigner).Assembly.ToString())
            Dim type = myassembly.[GetType]("System.Windows.Forms.Design.DataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog")
            Dim ctor = type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)(0)
            Return CType(ctor.Invoke(New Object() {provider}), Form)
        End Function

        Public Shared Sub SetLiveDataGridView(ByVal form As Form, ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
            Dim method = form.[GetType]().GetMethod("SetLiveDataGridView", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
            method.Invoke(form, New Object() {dgv})
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function EditValue(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal provider As IServiceProvider, ByVal value As Object) As Object
            If provider IsNot Nothing AndAlso context IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim service = CType(provider.GetService(GetType(IWindowsFormsEditorService)), IWindowsFormsEditorService)
                If service Is Nothing OrElse context.Instance Is Nothing Then Return value
                Dim host = CType(provider.GetService(GetType(IDesignerHost)), IDesignerHost)
                If host Is Nothing Then Return value
                If dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog Is Nothing Then dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog = CreateColumnCollectionDialog(provider)
                Dim dgv = (CType(context.Instance, MyDataGridView))
                Dim oldSite = dgv.Site
                dgv.Site = (CType(context.Instance, MyDataGridView)).Parent?.Site
                SetLiveDataGridView(dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog, dgv)

                Using transaction = host.CreateTransaction("DataGridViewColumnCollectionTransaction")

                    If service.ShowDialog(dataGridViewColumnCollectionDialog) = DialogResult.OK Then
                        transaction.Commit()
                    Else
                        transaction.Cancel()
                    End If
                End Using

                dgv.Site = oldSite
            End If

            Return value
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function GetEditStyle(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As UITypeEditorEditStyle
            Return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal
        End Function
    End Class
End Class


Partial Public Class DGVManager
    Inherits UserControl
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property DataGridView As DataGridView
        Get
            Return DGV
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

I'm obviously misunderstanding something, so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: But, is your DataGridView (DGV) derived from `MyDataGridView`? Or is it the default Control?

Comment: Also, is `DGVManager` (even though you name the class `DataGridViewManager` in your description) actually a full-fledged UserControl, or the code you have here, related to this UC, is all there is? If it is, then it's missing pieces (the entire designer file, to begin with)

Comment: Yes, the control worked with an external datagridview before I added the datagridview to the user control itself

Comment: The "DGV" datagrid view is a control I have dropped onto my user contol from the toolbox

Comment: That's not what i asked. Did you *convert* the code you found and you just pasted it into a Form? How is the `DGVManager` UserControl related to the UserControl, `DataGridViewManager`, you're referring to? -- The DataGridView you *dropped from the ToolBox*, is an instance of the custom `MyDataGridView` Control or an instance of the standard DataGridView -- If you just pasted that code into a Form, then there's no relation at all, so that code isn't going to do anything, except introduce compilation errors, since the `DGVManager` UserControl is incomplete (just a sample snippet)

Comment: Many thanks for your help. As you suspected I had inserted the code into the wrong part of my UC code.  I've now corrected that and I think I understand how it is supposed to work. However, I still get the error "Classes can only inherit from other classes" on the line "Inherits ITypeDescriptorContext" - which in the C# original was "public class TypeDescriptionContext : ITypeDescriptorContext". I've looked at the learn.Microsoft page for this but I didn't find it helpful. It's used in "Dim tdc = New TypeDescriptionContext(dataGridView1, columnsProperty)"

Comment: `ITypeDescriptorContext` is an Interface not a class. You don't usually implement this Interface, you receive it from the Designer context service. There's nothing in the C# code that implements this Interface or creates a stub class as described in your comment. The only class implemented is `UITypeEditor`

Comment: I can now compile and debug, but I've got stuck on a runtime error at "Dim field = context.Instance.[GetType]().GetField("_DGV", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)" (where "_DGV" is the name of my datagridview control. The statement returns "Nothing".

Comment: querying "context.instance" in the immediate window shows a list of proprties (including DGV, my property to return _DGV) but context.Instance.[GetType]().GetFields() returns an empty list.

Comment: Thanks to @jimi code now executes to the statement in EditValue (shown abouve) where

Comment: Thanks to @jimi code now executes to the statement in EditValue (shown abouve) where Dim host = CType(provider.GetService(GetType(IDesignerHost)), IDesignerHost) returns nothing.  ("Provider" is passed from the designer and shows its Component property = my user control.)